# Embedding a shiny app into reveal.js document

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

I am working with a revealjs_presentation in Rmarkdown and I want to include a Shiny app hosted in shinyapps.io but can't find the line of code to embed it.

I tried the method recommended [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-embedded.html) by embedding it directly to the file but that process yielded the following error "revealjs_presentation is not compatible with runtime shiny".

Comment: You want embed an iframe to the shinyapps.io link in your reveal document, or the R interactivity itself?

Comment: I tried using ```{r} <iframe id="example1" src="link" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 850px" frameborder="0">
</iframe> ``` inside a ##Slide and it did not work

Comment: I was able to display the app in a slide using <div>```{r, echo = FALSE, message=F, warning=F, results=F}
pacman::p_load(shiny)
shinyAppDir("path_to_app_dir/",
  options=list(
    width="100%", height=700
  )
) 
``` </div>  and taking runtime:shiny out of the YAML which produces a static image (not interactive), but I think the issue is that revealjs is not compatible with the shiny server

Answer (score 0):

Writing this works for me.

App is deployed elsewhere:

```
library(htmltools)

HTML('<section id = "Probability of presence heatmap" data-background-iframe="https://XXXXX.shinyapps.io/XXXXX/" data-background-interactive>
</section>')
```